# Docker is unable to start due to `dm_task_set_cookie failed`

Tags: docker, semaphore

I installed docker using command on centos machine using command

```
$ yum install docker
$ docker --version
Docker version 1.12.6, build 88a4867/1.12.6
```

When I start docker:

```
$ service docker start

    Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start  docker.service
    Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

$ systemctl status -l  docker.service
    docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
       Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
       Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2017-08-27 23:30:54 PDT; 39s ago
         Docs: http://docs.docker.com
      Process: 21772 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd-current --add-runtime docker-runc=/usr/libexec/docker/docker-runc-current --default-runtime=docker-runc --exec-opt native.cgroupdriver=systemd --userland-proxy-path=/usr/libexec/docker/docker-proxy-current $OPTIONS $DOCKER_STORAGE_OPTIONS $DOCKER_NETWORK_OPTIONS $ADD_REGISTRY $BLOCK_REGISTRY $INSECURE_REGISTRY (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
     Main PID: 21772 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

    Aug 27 23:30:53 tintserver7200 systemd[1]: Starting Docker Application Container Engine...
    Aug 27 23:30:53 tintserver7200 dockerd-current[21772]: time="2017-08-27T23:30:53.373296685-07:00" level=info msg="libcontainerd: new containerd process, pid: 21780"
    Aug 27 23:30:54 tintserver7200 dockerd-current[21772]: time="2017-08-27T23:30:54.386669163-07:00" level=warning msg="devmapper: Usage of loopback devices is strongly discouraged for production use. Please use `--storage-opt dm.thinpooldev` or use `man docker` to refer to dm.thinpooldev section."
    Aug 27 23:30:54 tintserver7200 dockerd-current[21772]: time="2017-08-27T23:30:54.387270412-07:00" level=error msg="[graphdriver] prior storage driver \"devicemapper\" failed: devmapper: Base Device UUID and Filesystem verification failed: devicemapper: Can't set cookie dm_task_set_cookie failed"
    Aug 27 23:30:54 tintserver7200 dockerd-current[21772]: time="2017-08-27T23:30:54.388221829-07:00" level=fatal msg="Error starting daemon: error initializing graphdriver: devmapper: Base Device UUID and Filesystem verification failed: devicemapper: Can't set cookie dm_task_set_cookie failed"
    Aug 27 23:30:54 tintserver7200 systemd[1]: docker.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
    Aug 27 23:30:54 tintserver7200 systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
    Aug 27 23:30:54 tintserver7200 systemd[1]: Unit docker.service entered failed state.
    Aug 27 23:30:54 tintserver7200 systemd[1]: docker.service failed.
```

Install info:

```
$ uname -a
Linux tintserver7200 3.10.0-514.6.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Jan 18 13:06:36 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

The docker daemon shows multiple errors for `Can't set cookie dm_task_set_cookie failed`:

```
$ sudo docker daemon -D

    DEBU[0000] docker group found. gid: 386
    DEBU[0000] Listener created for HTTP on unix (/var/run/docker.sock)
    INFO[0000] libcontainerd: new containerd process, pid: 32755
    DEBU[0000] libcontainerd: containerd connection state change: CONNECTING
    DEBU[0000] libcontainerd: containerd connection state change: TRANSIENT_FAILURE
    WARN[0000] containerd: low RLIMIT_NOFILE changing to max  current=1024 max=4096
    DEBU[0000] containerd: read past events                  count=0
    DEBU[0000] containerd: supervisor running                cpus=4 memory=7713 runtime=docker-runc runtimeArgs=[] stateDir=/var/run/docker/libcontainerd/containerd
    DEBU[0000] containerd: grpc api on /var/run/docker/libcontainerd/docker-containerd.sock
    DEBU[0001] Using default logging driver json-file
    DEBU[0001] Golang's threads limit set to 54630
    DEBU[0001] devicemapper: driver version is 4.34.0
    DEBU[0001] devmapper: Generated prefix: docker-253:0-582605
    DEBU[0001] devmapper: Checking for existence of the pool docker-253:0-582605-pool
    DEBU[0001] devmapper: Pool doesn't exist. Creating it.
    ERRO[0001] [graphdriver] prior storage driver "devicemapper" failed: devicemapper: Can't set cookie dm_task_set_cookie failed
    DEBU[0001] Cleaning up old mountid : start.
    FATA[0001] Error starting daemon: error initializing graphdriver: devicemapper: Can't set cookie dm_task_set_cookie failed
```

How can I resolve the error `Can't set cookie dm_task_set_cookie failed`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fixed I did echo 'y' | sudo dmsetup udevcomplete_all 
and it was able to start

Answer (score 1):

To clarify on the original question/answer here since [many](https://github.com/kubevirt/kubevirt/issues/321) [others](https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/85) have had this problem (or jump to the solution below):

The general issue here is that earlier versions of Docker could have `devicemapper` leak semaphores/cookies outside of a container's mount space. For me, this happened after doing multiple rapid calls to docker `build`, `run`, `rm`, `stop`, etc.

This could cause the system's semaphore arrays to fill up without being cleared, which would prevent all docker commands from working (and may impact other system functions relying on those shared semaphores).

You could solve this by [increasing the number of semaphore arrays](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12746/how-do-i-increase-the-number-of-semaphore-arrays-in-linux), or by clearing some of the old arrays as I do below.

---

The accepted answer uses [clearing all semaphores](https://linux.die.net/man/8/dmsetup) with `dmsetup udevcomplete_all`, but you may not want to do this if you have other containers or processes relying on those cookies/semaphores.

Instead, check your [semaphore arrays](https://linoxide.com/linux-how-to/semaphore/) -- these were full on my machine (128 arrays):

```
$ ipcs -u

------ Semaphore Status --------
used arrays = 128
allocated semaphores = 1136

------ Messages Status --------
allocated queues = 0
used headers = 0
used space = 0 bytes

------ Shared Memory Status --------
segments allocated 2
pages allocated 20057
pages resident  16214
pages swapped   2
Swap performance: 0 attempts     0 successes
```

These semaphores correspond to dm cookies, as shown with `ipcs` and `dmsetup udevcookies` (showing only recent cookies; look for the matching `semid`):

```
$ ipcs -s -t
semid    owner      last-op                    last-changed              
540278908 root        Sat Jun 13 10:03:57 2020   Sat Jun 13 10:03:57 2020  
548634749 root        Sat Jun 13 10:09:22 2020   Sat Jun 13 10:09:22 2020  
555876478 root        Sat Jun 13 10:14:05 2020   Sat Jun 13 10:14:05 2020  
572096639 root        Sat Jun 13 11:43:42 2020   Sat Jun 13 11:43:42 2020 
...

$ dmsetup udevcookies
Cookie       Semid      Value      Last semop time           Last change time
0xd4d819c    540278908  1          Sat Jun 13 10:03:57 2020  Sat Jun 13 10:03:57 2020
0xd4d8d60    548634749  1          Sat Jun 13 10:09:22 2020  Sat Jun 13 10:09:22 2020
0xd4d8eca    555876478  1          Sat Jun 13 10:14:05 2020  Sat Jun 13 10:14:05 2020
0xd4d7263    572096639  1          Sat Jun 13 11:43:42 2020  Sat Jun 13 11:43:42 2020
...
```

To avoid impacting the older semaphores/cookies, I wanted to release only cookies for certain dates using `msetup udevreleasecookie <cookie ID>`:

```
# filter the list of cookies, get the IDs, and feed it to udevreleasecookie:

$ REGEX_STR="Jun 13"    # change to whatever filter you need
$ dmsetup udevcookies | grep -E "$REGEX_STR" | awk '{ print $1 }' | xargs -n1 dmsetup udevreleasecookie

# check that the semaphores are gone
$ ipcs -s -t | grep -E "root" | grep -E "$REGEX_STR"    
...
$
```

This allowed me to run `docker` commands again.